# Misaligned layers - vector & raster

Tags: qgis, coordinates, feature-layer

[image]

I am doing geomorphological research in South Iceland using ArcticDEM data, LSD TopoTools software and QGIS.

I'm having an issue with my geology layer (an ArcGIS feature layer) being a few hundred metres out of alignment with my output rasters (derived from the software I'm using to analyse the landscape).

In the image the blue-tinted area is the hillshade raster; the orange, grey and speckled areas are part of the geology map, denoting different lithologies. If you look closely at the portion under the orange area, within blue-tinted raster (at the bottom), you can see how the extent of the misalignment. That "exposed" cliff is supposed to be included in the orange area.

I am fairly sure the issue is with the geology layer as my rasters and delimited text layers are aligned with each other, and with the world map (not pictured) I added through the XYZ file route (the rivers match up etc).

The CRS of the geology layer is WGS 84 and the CRS of the raster is UTM 27. I have tried changing them so they can be the same but it ends up sending the hillshade raster off to the Netherlands or rotating the geology layer 90° and placing it in Canada :/

I don't seem to have the ability/permission to use the Move Feature tool in QGIS to manually move the geology layer, and the Vector Geometry -> Translate method returns me red error messages in the Log saying the geometry is invalid.

I also have tried the Raster Projection -> Assign method which didn't work.

All I want is for the layers to allign! I am investigating knickpoints in rivers so the underlying geology is pretty important to my research. If you have any ideas of what I could be doing wrong or what I could do to solve the issue?

[image]

Comment: If you want to move features in a vector layer you first have to enable editing with the pencil button - done that? Then you can use the editing buttons to move and change features. But could you refer your text to your image? I'm struggling to see what's what there and what the misalignment is. Are there three layers in that? Can you compare them with a base layer like OpenStreetMap or ESRI?

Comment: Emma can you post a screenshot of your project, selecting the geology layer in the table of content? This way I can maybe see why you cannot edit/moved feature tool.

Comment: 1. I have added an explanation for the first photo. Hopefully this helps.
2. I am unable to 'enable editing' as the option to is greyed out.
3. Screenshot posted! Hopefully this helps too.

Comment: Emma you have to be more specific with your coordinate systems, do you have the EPSG codes for WGS 84 and  UTM 27? I suspect they do not have a common datum, which could explain the shift of a few hundred meters.